# Get tag information from openstreetmap, specifically tag info

Tags: python, api, nodes, openstreetmap

I have some code giving me information about the geotag of an image I have obtained from flickr. The code is the following:

```
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.reverse("{}, {}".format(lat, lon))
print(location.address)
print url
print(location.raw)
dict = location.raw
osmid = dict.get('osm_id', 'default_value_if_null_here')
osmtype = dict.get('osm_type', 'default_value_if_null_here')
print osm_type
```

I am obtaining the lat, lon and url variables from the image I obtain. Then using the geopy package I receive back the following results

```
5, Linnaeusweg, Paardenveld, IJsselstein, Bestuur Regio Utrecht, Utrecht, Nederland, 3401MS, Nederland
https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1456/24640378196_c096ea190b_m.jpg
{u'display_name': u'5, Linnaeusweg, Paardenveld, IJsselstein, Bestuur Regio Utrecht, Utrecht, Nederland, 3401MS, Nederland', u'place_id': u'37712154', u'lon': u'5.0540829', u'osm_type': u'node', u'licence': u'Data \xa9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright', u'osm_id': u'2919181986', u'lat': u'52.0175634', u'address': {u'town': u'IJsselstein', u'industrial': u'Paardenveld', u'house_number': u'5', u'country': u'Nederland', u'county': u'Bestuur Regio Utrecht', u'suburb': u'IJsselstein', u'state': u'Utrecht', u'postcode': u'3401MS', u'country_code': u'nl', u'road': u'Linnaeusweg'}}
node
```

The ultimate goal of my code is to somehow use openstreetmap to see if this location corresponds to some landmark. However for now my question is as follows.

If I take all the results that come back as osm_type node, how would I input the info I have received to openstreetmap to get info about the node such as the following example I found

```
< node id =" 592637238 " lat =" 47.1675211 " lon =" 9.5089882 "
       version ="2" changeset =" 6628391 "
       user =" phinret " uid =" 135921 "
       timestamp =" 2010 -12 -11 T19:20:16Z " >
   < tag k=" amenity " v=" bar " / >
   < tag k=" name " v=" Black Pearl " / >
```

If I could get this data maybe then I could use the tags to see if it is a landmark. I have looked into osmapi but I do not know how to use it

Sorry for how rambling my question is I am new to python also openstreetmap so any help would be so appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the node details via the API, example for your node with ID 2919181986: http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/2919181986. However keep in mind that Nominatim returns [nodes, ways and relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements), each element will need a slightly different API call. Another issue is that the corresponding landmark might be further away (e.g. when photographing a large building or mountain), so the nearest result must not be the correct one.

Another approach is to skip Nominatim completely and use [Overpass API](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API) instead for returning all data around the coordinates in question. This way you can look at all results and weight them by importance and distance. Also you will only need a single call for each coordinate because Overpass API already returns all tags.